# "Error calling Driver#connect" using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my cfg.xml file:

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=hiber;</property>
    <property name="connection.username">Costi-PC\Costi</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="model.User" />
```

User class and Main class:

```
@Entity
    public class User {

        @Id
        private int userId;
        private String userName;

        public int getUserId() {..}
        public void setUserId(int userId) {..}
        public String getUserName() {..}
        public void setUserName(String userName) {..}

    }

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           User user = new User();
           user.setUserId(1);
           user.setUserName("Costi");

           AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
           configuration.configure();

           SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

           Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
           session.beginTransaction();
           session.save(user);
           session.getTransaction().commit();
           session.close();

           sessionFactory.close();

}
```

When I run the program i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 14 more
```

I'm using sql server 2008.
I tried different types of cfg configuration  but none seems to work.
I believe the problem is from connection.url. I tried to change the port (1433) but nothing.
Can anyone tell what's the problem ?

Answer (score 7):

I have Faced Same issue just i have changed the Version on mysql  server connector than works fine

```
    <!-- commented as it was not make to connect 
       <dependency> 
          <groupId>mysql</groupId> 
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
          <version>5.1.34</version> 
       </dependency> 
   -->
```

added latest version of mysql connector

```
   <!-- added latest version of mysql connector -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.18</version>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is almost 2 years old, but for me the questions gave me, for me, the right answer. And because people with the same question are getting this post from Google. I thought, lets add my story.

Same thing, same problem. And for me the answer was that SQL Server didn't accept connections from the outside. The tcp/ip network client configuration is standard disabled.

So it was for me a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

I changed the version of MySql like,

From 5.1.8

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

To 8.0.19

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

It works for me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Use This with all Permission of DB**

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/dbname</property><property name="hibernate.connection.username">*******</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
```

Comment: app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the command line and see if sqlserver is indeed listening to that port. On windows this would be the command:

```
netstat -nao | findstr 1433
```

Then see if the PID is Sql Server as expected in the windows (Ctr+Alt+Delete) process list.

If the server is running, try to connect to it using a SQL client GUI, see here for [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496898/decent-simple-sql-server-client).  When you can connect to the database from an external client successfully, try again from the Java program.

Try to see also if your local firewall settings to see if the firewall is the cause for the error, although by default firewalls do not block  localhost - have a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/261402/corporate-firewall-blocking-localhost-127-0-0-1).

Answer (score 0):

Check you Sid in

> hibernate.cfg.xml file

For Oracle Express Edition:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
```

For Oracle Enterprise Edition:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't see he/she is using sql server 2008. Actually i am also facing same Exception.
I thing the problem in SID only

Answer (score 0):

the error is due to AnnotationConfiguration and making session by it.
you can try this solution:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(ce);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem due to some dependency issue. i solve my problem to change sql depenedency which is compatible to my current version of sql server in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error when migrating from jTDS1.2.8 to mssql-jdbc and for me it helped removing the port number and specifying the named instance in the connection URL within hibernate.cfg.xml

From:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://MYHOSTNAME:1433;databaseName=mydbname;instanceName=MYINSTANCENAME;</property>
```

To:

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://MYHOSTNAME;instanceName=MYINSTANCENAME;databaseName=mydbname;</property>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017

When using Named and Multiple SQL Server Instances, to use a JDBC URL property, do the following:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=instance1;integratedSecurity=true;<more properties as required>;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a virtual server or server that is not updated the time zone should update it.

SQL CONSOLE:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+3:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong username or a password in a config hibernate file "hibernate.cfg.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the database with which you are trying to connect has already been created in the database with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hibernate 4, try switching to Hibernate 5.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This helped me resolve the error.